# Detect if the mobile app is opened externally

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have a Cordova App and I am opening it from another APP (Salesforce1 app).
Is it possible to detect inside an Angular App (Using Cordova), whether the Application is launched externally.

Please advice, if any.

EDIT: I have two Apps - named app A and app B. both apps are hybrid and app B needs to be opened from app A. Now, I need to understand if I can read in App B, whether it is launched directly or opened externally.
e.g., App A is ionic project, and opening App B using the code:

```
navigator.app.loadUrl("http://myapp", {openExternal: true});
```

Now, When App B opens - I need to track whether it is opened from App A or not.

Please provide your inputs.

Thanks!

Comment: try to set flag from another app that indicates is app started from another app

Comment: Hi Akshay, Thanks for your answer. I am already doing that. But, where to check for that flag is something, which I wanted to know. I wanted the check to be done, whenever the Angular App is opened by tapping on it's Icon on homepage.